# Could you please verify if my code is correct for saving string to struct?

Tags: c++, structure, stringstream

I am trying to file input information from a .txt file that has three inputs i.e(Mike Jones 60) and inserting them into a structure C++ to use for my output to screen.

```
struct Person {
    string name;
    int age;
};
void addData()
{
    Person aPerson;
    char fileName[80];
    cout << "Please enter the file name: ";
    cin.getline(fileName, 80);
    //string fullName;
    ifstream fin(fileName);
    string tmp;
    stringstream ss;
    while (!fin.eof()) {
        getline(fin, aPerson.name);
        aPerson.name = tmp;
        getline(fin, tmp);
        ss << tmp;
        ss >> aPerson.age;
        ss.clear();
        getline(fin, tmp);
        ss.clear();
        cout << aPerson.name << aPerson.age << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the `Person` struct - are you going to extend this to store a container of `Person`s at some point? If not you could eliminate the `struct` and simplify the code a little.

Comment: The correct tool for such a task is a debugger, not asking random people to verify your code's correctness. It will be beneficial for you to read about [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will read data in this format:

```
Joe Bloggs
42

Franziska von Karma
23

Jeff Jefferson
84
```

Is that what your input data looks like?

If it's one line per person, and each person has **exactly** two words in their name, you can use the [third parameter of `getline` to set a custom delimiter](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) - instead of reading the whole line, it will read until it gets to a space.

```
Joe Bloggs 42
Jeff Jefferson 84
Amy Anderson 57
```

To process this data:

```
…
while (!fin.eof()) {
  string firstname;
  getline(fin, firstname, ' ');
  string surname;
  getline(fin, surname, ' ');
  aPerson.name = firstname + " " + surname;
  string age;
  getline(fin, age);
  ss << age;
  ss >> aPerson.age;
  cout << aPerson.name << aPerson.age << endl;
  ss.clear();
}
```

If you can get the data in Comma-Separated Data format, or tab-separated, or anything-that's-not-a-space-separated, you can use that delimiter and extract the data in two steps not three.

Comment: That works like a charm. THank you, question If I wanted to call just surname and the age in a function I would need to convert int to string ? If so how would I do that ?  C++ 5.1. Thank you.

Comment: I don't completely understand… if you've got the age into your program as an `int` it might as well remain as an `int`!

Comment: nvm I called it into another function as aPerson.age It would cause an error. But it didn't thank again.